# Define Icons for sub actions in Lotus Notes action bar

Tags: lotus-notes

Is there a possible way to define icons for sub actions in Lotus Notes?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal Action property settings

[image: Action bar button normal]

Sub-Action property settings

[image: Sub-Action bar button]

As you can see, there is no icon options in the properties box for the sub-action. You can only change the action type. So, sorry no it's not possible to add icons to sub-actions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as far as I can see, there's really no solution for this.